# How to reverse the progress on mat-progress-spinner

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using the spinner as a timer and I would like to reverse the progress direction. It's clockwise if you go from 0 to 100, but my percentage is going from 100 (15 minutes = 900 seconds) to 0 (time has run out).

```
<mat-progress-spinner [color]="primary"
   [value]="percentage"
   strokeWidth="8">
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

[image]

Comment: You can add a calculate the relative value. In your case, the value is (100 - seconds / 9).

Answer (score 0):

there two problems:

1.- Calculate the time in minutes seconds depending the value

I like use a Date object and date pipe

```
get time()
  {
    return new Date(0,0,0,0,0,900-9*this.value) 
  }

{{time|date:'mm:ss'}}
```

2.-make two divs centered, you can use, e.g.

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.div2
{
  z-index:100;
  position:absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And your .html

```
<div class="box">
  <mat-progress-spinner
        class="example-margin"
        color="primary"
        mode="determinate"
        [value]="value">
    </mat-progress-spinner>
  <div class="div2">{{time|date:'mm:ss'}}</div>
</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njeeh7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprogress-spinner-configurable-example.html)

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have already the percentage in the range 100 to 0 based on the duration. The problem is the direction of the "countdown" because my time is going from 15:00 to 00:00 (in the stackblitz it's going from 00:00 to 15:00))

Comment: use then `get time(){return new Date(0,0,0,0,0,9*this.value)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can trick with some CSS which I think is the best and the easiest solution until Material implements it as a directive.

**Horizontal flip** (in your case):

```
mat-progress-spinner {
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

**Vertical flip**:

```
mat-progress-spinner {
    -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
    transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```